# OnValidation databinding unexpected behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm using this line of code to databind my TextBox control to my object.

```
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", myObject, "Text", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

It works as expected. However if I change update mode to OnValidation then databinding is only working one way Object->Control. That means if I type anything in my textbox upon validation the value is reset to that of an object Text property. Not the other way around.

I have tried to replicate this issue in a test project but I have failed. All 'simpler' versions are working as expected.

What I can tell is that INotifyPropertyChanged property is implemented in an abstract class. My object inherits that class. Also, TextBox control is created and databound at runtime then added to form. I have tried all that in my test project and it worked so I'm missing something here.

Any hints on how to debug this is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: DataBinding is something very hard to debug if there is some strange problem, sorry. That's one of the most annoying things when using binding (in both `winforms` and `wpf`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When debugging databinding issues, I often add handlers on the Binding.Parse and Binding.Format events:

```
    Binding b = new Binding("Text", myObject, "Text", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation);
    b.Format += new ConvertEventHandler(formatHandler);
    b.Parse += new ConvertEventHandler(parseHandler);
    textBox1.DataBindings.Add(b);
    private void formatHandler(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
    {
        //put code and breakpoint here to inspect e.Value
    }

    private void parseHandler(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
    {
        //put code and breakpoint here to inspect e.Value
    }
```

The Parse event is fired when the control's bound value changes and is to be pushed to the underlying data source. In your case this would happen only when the control validates.

The Format event is fired when the underlying data source is changed and the value needs to be pushed to the control.

First you can check if the Parse event is even fired. if not then I suspect your control's validation is failing.

I hope this can help you debug.

Cheers